# Flow of the fork, how many forks do I have?

Tags: c, fork, ipc

I have executed this code. 
I know that the orders of the messages are in any order (because i explicitly did not use semaphores)
How does the flow of my program look and why?

The parent is executed so "baz" is printed once. Can somebody explain why "bar" is not printed? Why do I get "foo" (the if statement is true) two times and not one or three times(not that i want this but i want to understand the logic)(because a colleague says that i should get three times foo out of it)?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
  int p;
  p = fork();
  if (fork()==0) {
    if (execl("/bin/echo", "/bin/echo", "foo", 0) == -1) {
      fork();
    }
  printf("bar\n");
  }
  else {
    if (p!=0) execl("/bin/echo", "/bin/echo", "baz", 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a tip for future questions. To avoid downvotes (I'm not one of them), if the question is such that "If I just read the `man page`, I could probably figure it out...", you should probably try that first. People here are happy to help you with programming problems, but are not here to explain how to read basic documentation. While this question does show effort, it probably falls on the side of basic information.

Comment: You can literally just observe what this program does, either with `strace -f` or by inserting debugging prints (that include the value of `getpid()` so you know which process it is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`execl` does not return, it replaces the entire process image with /bin/echo.
There are therefore zero "bar"s.

```
    if (execl("/bin/echo", "/bin/echo", "foo", 0) == -1) {
      fork();
    }
    /* Not reached if execl succeeded.
    Because the exec family of functions replace the process image with
    another executable.  Flow will never return, unless there is an
    error. */
    printf("bar\n");
```

There are two "foo"s.

```
  int p;
  p = fork();
  /* Two processes now */
  if (fork()==0) {
      /* Two child processes here. */
      execl("/bin/echo", "/bin/echo", "foo", 0); /* (Simplification) */
      /* Two (/bin/echo foo) here, flow will never return back */
  }
```

There is one "baz".

```
int p;
p = fork();
/* if block removed for simplicity */
if (p != 0)
{
    /* Only the initial parent process. */
    execl("/bin/echo", "/bin/echo", "baz", 0);
}
```

Comment: What about the numbers of foo?

Comment: Should I get two or three times foo in the program?

Comment: `p = fork();` spawns a new process (2 in total). Each of those runs `if (fork() == 0)`, which spawns another 2 processes. The original 2 don't enter the `if` statement because `fork` returned a non-zero value in them. Therefore only the 2 newest processes run `execl`.

Comment: So what you are saying is that my colleague is wrong? And that I should have two times foo and one time baz.

Comment: @TanjaMeeren What do you mean, "should have"? You already gave us the facts in your original question: `baz` is printed once, `bar` is not printed at all, `foo` is printed twice. You already know your colleague is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand that the `exec` family of system calls replaces the entire program with some other program. In your case, the "echo" program. Anything beyond an `execl` call is not executed.

Here is what is happening:

1. Your parent process (call it p<sub>0</sub>) executes `p=fork()` that forks a clone process p<sub>1</sub>.
2. Again p<sub>0</sub> executes if (fork()==0) that forks another clone process p<sub>2</sub>.
3. p<sub>0</sub> then executes the body of the else statement that prints the "baz".
4. After being forked, p<sub>1</sub> executes the `if (fork()==0)` statement that forks another process p<sub>3</sub>. Like p<sub>0</sub>, p<sub>1</sub> will enter the else statement but will not print "baz" because `p` which was set when p<sub>0</sub> forked p<sub>1</sub> is actually equal to 0 (since p<sub>1</sub> is the child of p<sub>0</sub>).
5. p<sub>2</sub> enters the if-statement body and executes the execl function which replace the current program with the echo program that prints "foo".
6. Like p<sub>2</sub>, p<sub>3</sub> enters the if-statement body and executes the execl function which replace the current program with the echo program that prints "foo".

Answer (score 0):

The first `fork` creates two processes,
which then both do a second fork.

```
p0    (p=$pid)              //first fork
                p1  (p==0)  

   p01                p11      //second fork
      exec              exec
```

In the leaf children (`p01` and `p11`), this second `fork` is followed by an `exec`, which if successful, ends the old process image. This should give you two `foo`s on `stdout`.

The parents (`p0` and `p1`) then do the:

```
if (p!=0) execl("/bin/echo", "/bin/echo", "baz", 0);
```

`p!=0` test which may only succeed in `p0` (the original process).
This should give you a single `baz` on `stdout`.

---

(In real code you should also check for `fork` errors).